# Simpler syntax for C and C# conditional statements

Tags: c#, c, syntax, conditional-statements

I'd like to be able to compare ints and strings like this:

```
if(a==b==c==d==e)
```

Unfortunately, C# won't compile it (I'm not sure about C).

Any ideas if I can get round the problem, and why the C# team don't permit this simpler syntax? (rather than something cumbersome such as `a==b && a==c && a==d && a==e`).

As a separate query, what's wrong with if(someValue == (5 || 6 || 7 || 8)) instead of having to keep saying `someValue==5 || someValue==6 || etc. etc.`? Obviously, 1 or more is counted as 'true' by .NET, but I think we should replace that paradigm with a shorter syntax to ease reading and writing of code.

********* EDIT:
As someone has said in the comments, problems occur with `a==b==c==d==e` when using boolean logic due to precedence issues (e.g: `(false==false) == false`). However, such issues don't arise when using ints or strings.

Comment: `if(someValue==5 || 6 || 7 || 8)`  --> check operator precedence.

Comment: `a==b==c` is the same as  `(a==b) == c` which is very different form `a==b && b == c`

Comment: do you know the result of `(5 || 6 || 7 || 8)`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: In C#, it doesn't compile. In C, I'd guess 'True', but I'd like it to be repurporsed for simpler syntax, as hardly any people use ints for boolean logic.

Comment: Yeah, sort of. in `c`, a code like `if(someValue == (5 || 6 || 7 || 8))` boils down to `if(someValue == 1)` which is not what you want, right? :-)

Comment: The conditional comparison should be separate, not cluttered with multiple equal to sign.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Affirmative.

Comment: @DrKoch: Excellent point, but no such issues exist if you're using ints and strings instead of boolean values. I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: This is asking for a feature that simply won't be used a lot. It may be possible in C# but less so in C/C++ and the aim of C# to stay close to those languages is probably much more important.

Comment: And in with the down/close votes we come. Not many seem to care about language elegance or simplification. However, I appreciate all the answers here, as I've learnt a bit - so thanks to all regardless.

Comment: Language elegance is about readability, not about a little less typing. You haven't made a very good case for this 'feature'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Shorter code often IS more readable, and takes up less screen space. When visualizing code, it's trickier to look for values in a swamp of potentially long variable names, than it is to just see the values on their own.

Comment: You should take up APL then...

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Granted, not all shorter code is easier to read, but often it is, as in the cases I've given. IMO.

Comment: You can argue for anything that you think would be nice, but it simply wouldn't happen. The syntax that you propose already has a meaning in C (which you might or might not like). Nobody will change the language to make valid code invalid.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Of course. But I was wondering if there was a good fundamental reason why my method wasn't adopted in the first place (or for future languages). I haven't really seen a show-stopper yet.

Comment: @DanW, the reason is that usually these languages work with expressions. If you write `a == b == c` your future language might interpret that as `(a == b) == c` or `a == ( b == c)`. Whatever `(a == b)` has a type, you then have to compare it to `c`, e.g., and this wouldn't do what you want. You would have to invent some other syntax, something more set oriented like `{ a, b, c,  d ... } == { a }`, but which implementation already would be relatively complex, and much above the level C-like languages organize their instructions.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Fair point. Coming back to this years later, and I'm almost embarrassed :)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to check, whether all variables have the same values? Until they are primitive types (int, string, double, etc.), you can put them into distinct collection, and check if it will contain only one element, like so:

```
var collection = new[] {a,b,c,d,e};
if(collection.Distinct().Count() == 1)
{
    // means a==b==c==e
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but a that defeats the purpose of what I was originally trying to achieve - simpler, terser syntax.

Comment: You can create custom extension for IEnumerable<T> for such purposes, so syntax will be more "sugary".

Comment: Oh that sounds good. I still wonder why something like this is not part of the language by default though.

Comment: Look, that is quite simple so. What is the result of `a == b`, if `a` and `b` are int? Result is `bool`. And if you write `a==b==c`, you will be actually trying to compare `a == (b == c)`, which will result in comparing `int` to `bool`.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question to clarify that. Ints and strings should be treated differently to bools in this case.

Comment: You edit is actually kinda wrong. I mean, the reason it won't compile is, that when comparing more then 2 `int` or `string`, due to operators order, it will result in trying compare `int` to `bool`. Re-read my comment once more.

Comment: I know. I'm saying that for comparing strings with strings (or ints with ints), then such syntax should be allowed since there's no ambiguity.